# Image isn't displaying and is freezing app on phone. Coded in flutter. Following dbestech tutorial on youtube

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I am following a tutorial by dbstech on Youtube on creating a travel app in flutter. It's my first try with flutter and first time in years coding anything. I was doing fine up until an hour in to the video. I'm using VSCode I tried adding the image like he asked and here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 243, 243),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Good Morning"
                      ),
                      Image.asset("images/img1_png")
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Everything works fine without that one single line with Image asset. The good morning displays and I can switch pages using the bottom navigation bar. However with the image code, the app still opens on my phone, but the image doesn't display and nothing works in the app. The navigation bar is broken as well as the main issue of the image not displaying. I made sure I copied the code from the tutorial perfectly.

I made sure the indent when importing the image in pubspec is correct

```
assets:
  - images/
```

I made sure the path is correct in both the code and the pubspec file. I imported the image folder by copying it to the project rather than adding the folder to the workspace. Even tried using add to workspace and still didn't work.

No error messages seem to popup when I run the app, nor is there any red errors showing in the code

Comment: You wrote `"images/img1_png"` as the path, isn't it supposed to be `"images/img1.png"` ? Are you sure no error come up when running the app in debug ?

Comment: @ColinLazarini Thanks for the reply. I accidentally posted the code from before I changed that oops lol. But I figured out it was still a problem with my code, in pubspec I didn't realise assets: needed to be indented by 2 spaces. I did get an error code but I didn't realise it was an error code for over an hour... Redirected me to another dart file for image views that is made to display error codes outside of debug log

Comment: Oh yea indentation is important in yaml files. Cool you found it :)